# Render number of elements based on users input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I am trying to render multiple `Input` elements based on number that user enters. I store the value in my `count` constant that dynamically changes. Then in my `returnForm` function I am trying to return the elements using `for` loop, but with no luck.

```
const returnForm = () =>
    {
        let items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            items.push(
                <div key={i}>
                    <TextInput source="name" validate={required()} />
                    <br></br>
                    <ArrayInput source="tags" label="resources.vid.fields.tags" style={{ width: '40%' }}>
                        <SimpleFormIterator>
                            <TagsEdit addLabel={true} label="resources.vid.fields.tag" />
                        </SimpleFormIterator>
                    </ArrayInput>
                    <br></br>
                    <TagsList addLabel={true} label="resources.vid.fields.tagsList" />
                </div>
            );

            return items;
        }
    }
```

Elements are only rendered one time even though value of `count` is different. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `count` defined?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica in a seperate method, however I console.logged it in renderForm function and the value is correct.

Comment: You have to call returnForm in `render`, and update `count` with `setState`. Then, use `this.state.count` instead.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal I did all that obviously. I only posted relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

try to move return out of loop

Comment: That fixed the issue, cant believe I missed that. Thanks